# put h5_job for css

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask whether I can put h5_job for css?

```
h5_job{font-size:18px;margin:18px 0;color:#f00a81;font-weight:normal}
<h5_job>Call Me :</h5_job>+62 8175 278 69
```

Comment: Use `h5 class="job"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no. `<h5_job>` is not valid HTML. You can however make a custom CSS class and apply it to an element:

```
<style>
    .h5_job { 
        font-size:18px;
        margin:18px 0;
        color:#f00a81;
        font-weight:normal
    }
</style>

<h5 class="h5_job">Call Me :</h5>+62 8175 278 69
```

**Additional Information**

See [Custom CSS Classes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Project_talk%3aCustom_CSS_Classes).

Comment: Alternatively, make the class `job` and use `h5.job`.

Answer (score 0):

`h5_job` isn't valid html tag.

however for set margins you must put `display:block;`